# Unable to execute shell script with parameter from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm creating a Dockerfile to customize an image named jboss/wildfly. I need to execute the following command:

```
/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-datasource.cli
```

The command works fine on my host machine, when translated into Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh", "--file=","/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-datasource.cli"]
```

The following error is returned:

> 'add-datasource.cli' is assumed to be a command(s) but the commands to
>   execute have been specified by another argument: [--file]

Any help ?

Comment: Are you executing something are creating the image, if so then you should be using CMD instruction instead of the RUN cmd ref: https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Comment: Thanks. Tried with CMD but the result is the same.

Comment: can you share the syntax for the CMD instruction which you tried ?

Comment: You syntax looks fine, comment the CMD line in your docker file, start the container with /bin/bash and execute the command manually within the container and check the output.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it just now and it works fine. Just like on the host machine. I suspect that the "--" switch disturbs the execution from CMD......

Comment: try putting in the CMD only a script that runs your whole line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the syntax you're using. You've split the `--file=` incorrectly. You need either:

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh", "--file=/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-datasource.cli"]
```

or

```
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh", "--file", "/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-datasource.cli"]
```

The command you have specified would parse as `--file= /opt/...` which isn't a valid command line.